# Can OpenSSH automatically disconnect session at end of cert-based key's valid period?

Tags: ssh, security, ssh-keys

I'm aware of the ability to logout inactive SSH sessions after a period of time but leaving something like "top" open works around that.

This question is more in the context of forceful disconnects and likely with cert-based keys.

**For example, take a cert-based key that's only valid for 24 hours. I'm wondering if it's possible to have SSH automatically disconnect the open session when the cert end date is reached?**

For the situations I'm thinking of forceful disconnects won't be an issue.

If there's a way to forcefully disconnect all sessions after a period of time, like 24 hours. That would be also be useful.

Comment: On a Linux system, ps -eo start_time,args | grep "sshd" will show you a list of ssh processes (excluding the master processes) along with how long ago they were started.  It would not be to hard to write a script to check if the first field has a ":" in it, and if not, kill the process as its more then 24 hours old - and then run this script periodically from cron.

Answer (score 1):

Good question; a quick test on my own Ubuntu 18.04.3 system suggests that no, it will not logout a user. [man sshd](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd) for BSD suggests that `expiry-time` offers the time after which the key will not be accepted.

My understanding of most SSH systems is that authentication is done at login, and not done again, although I see no reason why a server could not re-authenticate at each command input.  I can't find information that suggests my understanding is incorrect.